# tikz: Can we set the corner coordinates of a rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I already have

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=yellow!20, text centered, rectangle,
minimum height=0.8cm,minimum width=6em, align=right]
```

First, I can obtain a rectangle by

```
\node (rect) [block] at (0,0) {test};
```

Second, I can also obtain a rectangle by

```
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

**Question**: I want to use the first way to create a rectangle, whose properties have been predefined using \tikzstyle. If using the second way, I have to define the properties of the rectangle again. I know the coordinates of the corners of the rectangle can be obtained by

- rect.north east
- rect.north wast
- rect.south east
- rect.south west

**Can I create a rectangle using the first way and specify the four corner coordinates of the rectangle?**

Comment: You have conflicting objectives, you are providing a minimum width but then asking to be 1cm wide and high. Note that a node is not a ordinary path, it's a more complex object.

Comment: See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/16595).

Comment: @percusse The `rectangle` path could not care less about the node specific styles (only the unknowing user might wonder). More interestingly, I find `text centered` _and_ `align=right`, though my current PGF manual does not know about `text centered` anyway.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes you have even more for example `text badly ragged`; check line 775 onwards in `tikz.code.tex` file. They are kind of the older (or maybe lower) versions of `align=....` options. I know them from the auto-complete options of QTikZ.

Comment: @percusse I have only said that my manual doesn’t know about them. `;)` After all, there were no error messages, so TikZ at least knew them. And yes, they practically are `align=` without setting the `node halign header`. On that note, @Shiyu: `align=right` overwrites `text centered`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Though, I limited your question to two corner coordinates, because unless you account for rotation, two coordinates suffice to specify a rectangle.

### So many possibilities.

But before I divulge the actual solution to you let me give you some other ideas on positioning.

1. The `anchor=` key. It can be used as for example `anchor=south west` (see my example below) which set the south-west corner of the to-placed node at the `at` part.
2. With the `positioning` library you can even be more specific and could specify `above right=<distance> of <coordinate>` where `<coordinate>` can be an actual coordinate like `0,0` (enbrace the whole argument in `{ }` when you use `,` in it!), a node or a node’s anchor.

   Unless `<distance>` is specified, none is used. This topic is a bit complex, it is best to read subsection 17.5.3 “Advanced Placement Options” of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).
3. The `fit` library and its `fit=` key. The `fit` key takes a list of coordinates (or nodes, or anchors) and fits the to-be-fitted node so that those coordinates are enclosed by that node. But be aware of the `inner sep` key and the usual dimension-setting keys (height, width, etc.) as they can affect the placement; usually the corners do not lie at those coordinates.
4. My solution: the `from=<coordinate 1> to <coordinate2>` key. See the last point on the next list.

### So many styles.

I have created four distinctive styles:

1. `block filldraw` contains

   - `draw` and
   - `fill`
     options. It is used in the other styles and on the `rectangle` path.
2. `block rect` contains

   - `block filldraw` (and inherits its option) and
   - the node-specific `rectangle` option (which is the default).
     This style can be applied to an path but doesn’t change much for the path unless it contains a node which would than inherit those node-specific styles (but not the `draw` and `fill` styles).
3. `block` contains

   - `block rect`,
   - `minimum height` and
   - `minimum width`.
     Again, it does not change much for paths but for nodes.
4. `from` style (that should be used on a node) takes its argument in the form

   ```
   from=<coordinate 1> to <coordinate 2>
   ```

   Now, those coordinates can be just arbitrary `0,0` but than the whole argument must be enclosed in `{ }` (as I did in my example below). But they also can be nodes and their anchors.
   `<coordinate 1>` will be used as the lower left corner in the `above right=of` key.

   Both coordinates will be used to calculate the horizontal and vertical dimensions for the node. Note that I have used the `minimum width` and `minimum height` keys to set the needed dimensions. In this case, the node will grow with its content.

In the example I have set the `opacity` key to see the overlaying nodes and how they get positioned.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    block filldraw/.style={% only the fill and draw styles
        draw, fill=yellow!20},
    block rect/.style={% fill, draw + rectangle (without measurements)
        block filldraw, rectangle},
    block/.style={% fill, draw, rectangle + minimum measurements
        block rect, minimum height=0.8cm, minimum width=6em},
    from/.style args={#1 to #2}{% without transformations
        above right={0cm of #1},% needs positioning library
        /utils/exec=\pgfpointdiff
            {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)\relax}
            {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#2)\relax},
        minimum width/.expanded=\the\pgf@x,
        minimum height/.expanded=\the\pgf@y}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.4]
\draw[block filldraw]              (0,0) rectangle (1,1)       ;
\node[block] (rect)             at (0,0)                 {test};
\node[block, anchor=south west] at (0,0)                 {test};
\node[block rect, from={0,0 to 2,.5}]                 {from-to};

\foreach \x/\y/\pos in {0/0/below,1/1/above,2/.5/right}
  \fill[opacity=1] (\x,\y) circle (1pt) node [\pos] {$\x,\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Code with `fit` and animation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    block filldraw/.style={% only the fill and draw styles
        draw, fill=yellow!20},
    block rect/.style={% fill, draw + rectangle (without measurements)
        block filldraw, rectangle},
    block/.style={% fill, draw, rectangle + minimum measurements
        block rect, minimum height=0.8cm, minimum width=6em},
    from/.style args={#1 to #2}{% without transformations
        above right={0cm of #1},% needs positioning library
        /utils/exec=\pgfpointdiff
            {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#1)\relax}
            {\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(#2)\relax},
        minimum width/.expanded=\the\pgf@x,
        minimum height/.expanded=\the\pgf@y}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\hideme[1]{\ifnum\iCount<#1\relax\tikzset{every node/.style={opacity=0}}\fi}
\begin{document}
\foreach \iCount in {0,...,4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.6]
\draw[block filldraw]              (0,0) rectangle (1,1)       ; \hideme1
\node[block] (rect)             at (0,0)                 {test}; \hideme2
\node[block, anchor=south west] at (0,0)                 {test}; \hideme3
\node[block rect, from={0,0 to 2,.5}]                 {from-to}; \hideme4
\node[block rect, fit={(0,0)(1,1)}]                       {fit};  
\foreach \x/\y/\pos in {0/0/below,1/1/above,2/.5/right}
  \fill[opacity=1] (\x,\y) circle (1pt) node [opacity=1, \pos] {$\x,\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Output with `fit` and animation

[image]

Comment: Nice. You can also get the same effect by `\node[block,fit={(0,0)(1,1)}] {test};` with inner and outer sep dimensions reset to zero and minimum size removed (via fit library).

Comment: @percusse Well, now that you have mentioned it, I’ll add `fit` to my answer. Though I find the need to set the seps to zero as a disadvantage. Nonetheless, it is a valid option and, in other cases, a good alternative.

Comment: Dear Lord! So many solutions. Tikz is always much more complicated than I think. Thanks a lot! Excellent answer!